# all maps are measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

A map $T:X  \rightarrow Y$ is $A, B$- measurable if the pre-image of every set in $B$ is a set in $A$, where $A,B$ are $\sigma$-algebras in $X,Y$.

But I was thinking that isn't any map $T: X \rightarrow Y$ measurable then? Because since pre-images behave so nicely, the pre-image of all sets from $B$ make up a $\sigma$-algebra in $X$, and thus the definition is satisfied?

Answer (score 1):

It is true that preimages of $B$ form a sigma-algebra in $X$. However, there is no a priori reason why this sigma-algebra should be contained in $A$.

Comment: Hm. But is it then $C \backslash B$-measurable, where $C$ $\textit{is}$ the pre-image $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: @iikaosero: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 1):

That's not true, of course.

Here's an example which doesn't require us to be in any special setting: Let $X$ be any set and let $\mathcal A$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ that is a strict subset of $\mathcal P(X)$. Let $A \in \mathcal P(X) -\mathcal A$. Then: $1_A - 1_{A^C}$ is not measurable.

A part of what you are saying is true, though. The set $f^{-1}(\mathcal B)$ does form a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, but it simply isn't necessarily $\subseteq \mathcal A$, the presumed $\sigma$-algebra on $X$.

IMO one must refer to a measurable space as $(X, \mathcal A)$ rather than just $X$ when one is still a beginner. This allows one to avoid possible misconceptions. What I mean is: had you written $T: (X, \mathcal A) \to (Y, \mathcal B)$, you wouldn't have had this confusion, I think.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: The more sets you have in the $\sigma$-algebra of $X$ and the less sets you have in the $\sigma$-algebra of $Y$, the more "likely" your function is to be measurable.

I'm sure you can think of some trivial nonmeasurable examples now.